# Applescript- combine multiple IF statments and an abbreviation for home folders

Tags: applescript, directory, home-directory

I'm trying to make an applescript to make a backup of some files to dropbox. My question was if it was possible to combine multiple IF statmens in my script and if it was possible to make a shorten SET name TO path, like Macintosh HD:Users:svkrzn:Dropbox to ~:Dropbox.

Here is my script:

```
set destination to "Macintosh HD:Users:svkrzn:Dropbox:Backup"
set safari to "Macintosh HD:Users:svkrzn:Library:Safari:Bookmarks.plist"
set safariplist to "Macintosh HD:Users:svkrzn:Dropbox:Backup:Safari_Bookmarks.plist"
set things to "Macintosh HD:Users:svkrzn:Library:Application Support:Cultured Code:Things:Database.xml"
set thingsxml to "Macintosh HD:Users:svkrzn:Dropbox:Backup:THINGS_Database.xml"

tell application "Finder"
    try
    set S1 to duplicate file safari to folder destination with replacing
    set T1 to duplicate file things to folder destination with replacing
    if exists file safariplist then
        display dialog "It exists."
        delete file safariplist
    end if
    if exists file thingsxml then
        display dialog "It exists."
        delete file thingsxml
    end if
    set name of S1 to "Safari_Bookmarks.plist"
    set name of T1 to "THINGS_Database.xml"
 on error
    display dialog "Oops, a problem occurred duplicating the file."
 end try
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

If statements can be like this...

```
if something then
    -- do something
else if somethingElse then
    -- do something else
else if anotherThing then
    -- do the other thing
else
    -- if none of the others are true then do this
end if
```

In applescript we use the "path to" command to get to standard folders. Applescript knows a lot of standard folders. Open AppleScript Editor, under the "Window" menu choose "Library". Find the "Standard Additions" application and double-click it to open Applescript's Standard Additions dictionary. Search for "path to" and see all of the standard folders Applescript knows about.

For example you could do this...

```
set destination to (path to home folder as text) & "Dropbox:Backup"
```